Extension complexity - Equivalent definitions
I'm confused by two, apparently equivalent, definitions of extension complexity.
See the attached screenshot: 
From: Sparse sums of squares on finite abelian groups
and improved semidefinite lifts
Hamza Fawzi, James Saunderson, Pablo A. Parrilo
Take for example the naive LP lift of $P$, by simply taking as $Q$ the set $P$ itself. Then $Q$ has the same number of facets as $P$. Thus, by the second definition of extension complexity $\mathrm{xc}_{\mathrm{LP}}(P) \leq p$, for $p$ the number of facets of $P$.
However, taking the naive LP lift for equation (10), we require that $L$ is an affine subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$: here $n$ is the number of variables in $P$, i.e., $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. We need $n+p$ variables; $n$ for the number of variables in $P$, and $p$ slack-variables for each of the $p$ facets of $P$. This would give $\mathrm{xc}_{\mathrm{LP}}(P) \leq n+p$, which is not the same bound as the previous derivation.
Specifically, if
$$P := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+ : 1 \leq x \leq 2, \, 1 \leq y \leq 2 \},$$
then I can take
$$L = \{ (x,y,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4) \in \mathbb{R}^6_+ : x+s_1 = 2, -x+s_2 = -1, y+s_3 = 1, -y+s_3 = -1\},$$
and since $L \in \mathbb{R}^6_+$, $\mathrm{xc}_{\mathrm{LP}}(P) \leq 6$, but $P$ only has 4 facets, so $\mathrm{xc}_{\mathrm{LP}}(P) \leq 4$. (I know that both can be true at the same time, this is not a contradiction. However, I expect the trivial construction to reach the same bounds in both definitions)
What am I missing here?
